Can using Fetch in an SQL select statement return more than one set of data?
I would like to go through a table that 50000 entries by doing 10K at a time.  This would help with processing time.  Can the statement be used to go through this table in 10K chunks until all 50000 have been processed or does it only return the first 10000 and that is it?
SELECT
  "field-1",
  "field-2",
  "field-3",
  "field-4",
FROM table1
WHERE table1."sort-field" = 'TEST'
ORDER BY table."grouping-field" ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY


Is grouping-field unique? If it's not, then it won't be possible to paginate.

Please tag the rdbms you are using

The exact statement you posted will only ever get the first chunk, but you can easily modify it to get the other chunks by changing the OFFSET clause to use the correct value each time (0-indexed chunk number * chunk size), as long as you also meet these two conditions:

The ORDER BY clause is fully-deterministic, with no wiggle-room for ties among multiple rows with the same order rank. Otherwise you could pull the same rows across two chunks, while missing some others.
The data does not change between when you get chunks (otherwise you might miss rows)

There's an additional caveat for large tables where the performance isn't always great, because for each later chunk the database still has to compute record order from all the items preceding it.
If the situation allows it, one alternative is using a forward-only connected data access pattern instead of a "load all to an array" access pattern. In .Net parlance, that means reading from a DataReader instead of using a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable. This comes with the risk of holding locks on the table, but allows you to stream records from the DB one at a time, as fast as the DB can deliver them and your app can process individual records, instead of needing to load everything all at once before it can process anything.
